# Googlemaps V3 - Draggable Polygon Error

Tags: google-maps

Below is a standard code taken from Google Map api V3 documentation. If you chnage the polygon options to editable and draggable, when you hover/click on the vertices of the polygon, you get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of null

The error is inconsistent in that it appears on an ad-hoc basis.

```
  function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            drawingControl: false,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: ['marker', 'circle', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'rectangle']
            },
            markerOptions: { icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png' },
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#ffff00',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 5,
                clickable: true,
                editable: true,
                draggable:true,
                zIndex: 1
            }
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {

            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
        });

    }

          initMap();
```

Is this a bug in the api ? 
Would appreciate any input on this matter.
Many thanks.